# kill unresponsive process

Tags: linux-kernel, kill

According to `top`, process named `pccardd` loads my CPU nearly 100%:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                    
  530 root      20   0     0    0    0 R  96.6  0.0  62:01.52 pccardd
```

According to `ps`, the process is running state:

```
root@T60:~# ps -o pid,ppid,command,state,uid,pcpu -p 530
  PID  PPID COMMAND                     S   UID %CPU
  530     2 [pccardd]                   R     0  0.2
root@T60:~#
```

If I try to kill the `pccardd` with `SIGTERM` or `SIGKILL` signals, then nothing happens. I am aware that `kill -9` may not work immediately, but I have waited well over an hour. Is it possible that `pccardd` process executes some system calls and thus `SIGKILL` signal is blocked? I tried to ensure this with `strace`, but I can't:

```
root@T60:~# strace -p 530
attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): Operation not permitted
root@T60:~#
```

Is there a way to kill this `pccardd` process or am I forced to reboot the machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only ways for a process to receive a SIGKILL and still remain are:

1. The process is in uninterruptable sleep state (denoted as `D`).
2. The process is a zombie (denoted as `Z`).
3. It's a kernel process.

The brackets (`[]`) around the process name in the `ps` output would indicate #3, it's a kernel process.

So you can't kill it. You also can't `strace` the kernel either.

The only possible solution you might have is to remove the module associated with this process. However I do not know what that module is.
I'd also check `dmesg` for related messages, and search the web for bugs.